# VERILOG issue with struct

Tags: struct, verilog, system-verilog

I have an unsolved problem with the use of struct in Verilog.

Here is my code :

---

```
//Other technic
//typedef struct{bit Over_I;}reg_type;

// Code 
module Overload(rst_n,clock,vlowp,IHigh,Over_I);

    // Port declaration
    input rst_n,clock,vlowp,IHigh;
    output Over_I;

    reg S_NOM = 0;
    reg S_OVL = 1;

    struct{
        reg Over_I;
    } reg_type;

    reg_type Reg,NextReg;

    initial
    begin 
        Over_I = Reg.Over_I;
    end
```

---

I tried with a typedef outside the module without success.

The error given by the console is :

"ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/....../Lattice_tests/Test_Verilog/sources/overload_test.v" Line 26: Syntax error near "{".

The line 26 is the line where i defined struct.

If someone can help me, i would be grateful.
Thanks.
Franckois

Answer (score 1):

Verilog does not support struct data types. SystemVerilog (the successor of Verilog) does. All modern Verilog simulators are SystemVerilog simulators. You can enable SystemVerilog by changing the file extinction from `.v` to `.sv`
Most simulators have a compile option to force all Verilog files as SystemVerilog, but you will need to refer to the manual and it is not recommended. There is a lot of legacy Verilog code that used variable/net names that conflict with SystemVerilog keywords (ex `bit` and `byte`). The simulator can correctly parse the files correctly if the file extensions are used correctly.

Also `initial` will only assign something once. `Over_I` will not have the value of `Reg.Over_I` after time 0. Plus a wire (the default type of an output) cannot be assigned within a procedural block (eg `initial` and `always` blocks). Use an `assign` statement or make it an `output reg` and assign it in an (assuming SystemVerilog) `always_comb` or `always_ff` block, or Verilog `always` block.